# Are 9150 shifters and wireless compatible with 9100 Rear Derailleur?

Tags: derailleur-rear, shimano-di2

I’m getting Di2 for the first time and have 9150 crankset, shifters, and front derailleur. I was hoping to leverage the wireless features to - do I need to get the 9150 rear derailleur or can I settle with the 9100 rear derailleur? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Shimano Dura-Ace 9100 series components are mechanical; the 9150 series (Di2) are electronic, so you can't mix a 9150 shifter with a 9100 derailleur.